# how to append double quote,where double quote is not appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have following string

```
(Very strong=="Very strong"?100:(Very strong=="Above Average"?75:(Very strong=="Average"?50:(Very strong=="Below Average"?25:(Very strong=="Cannot determine"?0:(Very strong=="Poor"?0:0))))))
```

My desire out put is

```
  ("Very strong"=="Very strong"?100:("Very strong"=="Above Average"?75:("Very strong"=="Average"?50:("Very strong"=="Below Average"?25:("Very strong"=="Cannot determine"?0:("Very strong"=="Poor"?0:0))))))
```

How i can append double quotes?where double quotes is not added.

Thanks

Comment: What is the beginning of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems very strange you need to do this, but if the structure will always be the same it is a pretty easy reg exp.

```
var str = '(Very strong=="Very strong"?100:(Very strong=="Above Average"?75:(Very strong=="Average"?50:(Very strong=="Below Average"?25:(Very strong=="Cannot determine"?0:(Very strong=="Poor"?0:0))))))'
var updated = str.replace(/\(([^=]+)/g,'("$1"');
console.log(updated);
```

basic reg ex description:

```
\(      - match a (
([^=]+)  - capture one or more characters that is not a =
```